# Extending HandlerThread and when to call getLooper()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I have a simple Activity with a button on it. Upon the button's onClick method, I want to run some code in another thread, getting a HandlerThread's Looper object and then posting a Runnable to the Handler associated with it.
My objective is to call a thread's method from another thread (and run it from its own thread) using Handlers (probably a bad idea, but I wanted to learn this instead of abusing static methods)

So I decided to extend HandlerThread. The new class does not really do much.

```
public class EpicThread extends HandlerThread {
    public EpicThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

The activity does not really do much either. I did this for some testing.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EpicThread et;
    Looper l;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EpicThread et = new EpicThread("The epic thread");
        et.start();
    }

    public void click(View v) {
        l = et.getLooper();
        Handler h = new Handler(l);
        h.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("This is running on the epic thread");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So I test this by pressing the button, which gives me a InvocationTargetException when `getLooper()` is called:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(23262): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(23262): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3660)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17088)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3655)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(23262): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    at com.asdf.qwert.MainActivity.click(MainActivity.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime(23262):    ... 14 more
```

Fiddling a little with this code, I noticed that :

- Getting the Looper with `l = et.getLooper();` works right after creating the thread, after `et.start();`.
- If I use HandlerThread directly instead of EpicThread, it works regardless of when `getLooper()` is called.

So I have no idea why this exception is thrown, and why simply by not using a subclass things started to work.

Comment: in EpicThread et = new EpicThread... you create a local variable et

Comment: and there is no need in extending HandlerThread,  just use base HandlerThread class

Comment: looper is best at static..

Comment: Where do you set the `onClickListener` for your button? Do you do it in XML? Have you named the XML click listener correctly? (i.e. android:onClick="click")?

Comment: @pskink Thanks for pointing this out... I overlooked this detail.

Comment: @AlexLockwood The XML is properly configured, as I would probably get a `NoSuchMethodException` if I mistyped the name

Comment: I know the 1st comment solved the issue, but why did you want to extend the HandlerThread ?